# Stripe multiple transactions

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have created a custom post type and each custom post type holds an order.
When an item reaches a certain amount of orders I wish to process the payments.

```
    if ($orders > 10){
//Charge Customers
}
```

Im using Stripe checkout and creating a customer, and storing this plus the amount, plus the original item chosen to the post meta

```
add_post_meta( $post_id , 'theme_cust_id', esc_attr( $cust_id ));
add_post_meta( $post_id , 'theme_item_name', esc_attr( $event_metadata->item_name ));
add_post_meta( $post_id , 'theme_amount', esc_attr( $event_metadata->amount ));
```

All this is working fine but I'm not really sure where to go from here, I need to be able to process all the charges for the item using the details I have.
I am a novice web dev so I'm probably just missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't say if you've done this or not, but you will need to [create your products in Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api#products).

Then, when you are ready to bill your customer, you simply [create a new order](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_order) (or if you want to keep orders in Stripe separate like in your WP system, one order per WP order) and that's all there should be to it!

Hope this helps!